# How to place a column of TH in a row of TH

Tags: html, html-table, css-tables

I'd like to make an HTML table with a "`<th>` split", like this:

[image: This is what I tried to make in the HTML table]

I tried to make the HTML table by splitting the `<th>` tag using `rowspan` and `colspan`, but I need it exactly like in the image.

Comment: So how does your attempt look like and where and how exactly does it have shortcomings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `rowspan` as you will use an inner table to compose the 4 rows [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/s9bbnyvh/1/)

```css
table {
  width: 98%;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#t1 table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD</td>
          <td>TD</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to  css https://jsfiddle.net/parthmy007/s7v70dk7/

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4">Items</th>
            <th rowspan="4">Type</th>
            <th rowspan="4">Type</th>
            <th colspan="4">Values</th>
            <th>Values</th>
            <th rowspan="4">Date</th>
                    <th rowspan="4">Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Before</th>
            <th >Before</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Before</th>



        </tr>

       <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Before</th>
            <th >Before</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/parthmy007/s7v70dk7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/ryrL79pr/

```
<html>
<body>


<table>

<tr>
  <th rowspan="4">A</th>
  <th rowspan="4">B</th>
  <th rowspan="4">C</th>
  <th>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </th>
  <th rowspan="4">D</th>
  <th rowspan="4">E</th>
  <th rowspan="4">F</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>3</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="3">Client</th>
                                            <th rowspan="3">Apt No</th>
                                            <th rowspan="3">Sq.ft Area</th>
                                            <th rowspan="3">Listed Price</th>
                                            <th>Date 28-FEB-2015</th>
                                            <th>Date 28-FEB-2015</th>
                                            <th>Date 28-FEB-2015</th>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                              <th>1st Instalment</th>
                                              <th>2nd Instalment</th>
                                              <th>3rd Instalment</th>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                              <th>10%  status</th>
                                              <th>10%  status</th>
                                              <th>10%  status</th>

                                        </tr>
</table>
```